# Setting $PATH and $JAVA_HOME from IzPack install.xml

Tags: path, installation, environment-variables, izpack, java-home

I see that $JAVA_HOME is a built-in variable in IzPack. Can I assign to it in a pre-install script and have the installer use that? Currently I am stuck on a machine that defaults to an open-source JRE that runs horribly and I need to reassign it to the Sun JRE so that the installer will run properly.

In the pre-install script, can I append to the $PATH with:

```
${ENV[PATH]} = ${ENV[PATH]}:/usr/local/java/bin
```

Let me know what I can do, I cannot get access to write to the .cshrc or .cshrc.login and I cannot tell my users to set the environment variables themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this for me was that I had to write a python script that set the environment variables and then called a subprocess to launch the installer. This is far from ideal, but it seems like if your machine is stuck by default with an open source JRE, then you can't fix that any other way.